# How to understand the Planck data?

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, astronomy, terminology

I want to analyze the Planck data to get relevant Cosmological parameters from it. But I don't know how can I go about this.

Can anyone guide me? Online sites/Research papers would be nice.

I know basic Cosmology from Scott Dodelson's book.

P.S - What is "PCP13"? I searched in Google and many research papers had something like - " as already done in PCP13". But I don't know what that is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PCP13 refers to "Planck Collaboration Paper 2013", here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.5075.  This is their first CMB parameter estimation analysis.

The research you are about to undertake involves 4 main ingredients: a statistical sampling framework, code to compute CMB spectra from input parameters, a likelihood function for evaluating these computed spectra, and, of course, the data.

COSMOMC is the standard package for doing parameter estimation.  It includes CAMB, a Boltzmann code for computing CMB spectra. It works with the likelihood functions provided by the various CMB experiments (WMAP, Planck, etc).  Start here: https://cosmologist.info/cosmomc/readme_planck.html.

There are lots of moving parts: multiple software packages, data sets, etc, and so getting everything to work can be tricky.  Once the analysis gets underway, you'll need to understand Monte Carlo Markov Chains and have a good handle of Bayesian inference.